# Does my function use recursion correctly?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to use a recursive function to find the greatest common denominator between two numbers entered by a user.
Recursion is still a little confusing for me and I've been told that I have a tenancy not to use it.
Does the function below count as using recursion? I'm still new to coding.

```
def gcd(m, n):

   #Determine bases
   if m==0:
      return n
   if n==0:
      return m

   #Find the lowest number
   if m > n:
      lowest = n
   else:
      lowest = m

   for i in range(1,lowest + 1):
      if((m % i == 0) and (n % i == 0)):
         gcd = i

   return gcd

def main():
   # take input from the user
   num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
   num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

   print("The GCD. of", num1,"and", num2,"is", gcd(num1, num2))

main()
```

Comment: It isn't recursive at all. Also, using the function name as a local variable isn't recommended (and it doesn't count as recursion). Furthermore, as far as a nonrecursive gcd goes, this one is quite inefficient. Better to read up on Euclid's algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common recursive method to determine the greatest common divisor is

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)

>>> gcd(100, 75)
25
```

An iterative method is

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    return a

>>> gcd(100, 75)
25
```

Note that the difference is that the recursive method calls itself over and over until hitting the base case (`b == 0`). The iterative method has a `while` loop, which is what makes it iterative.

Comment: Oh wow that's a lot better than what I was working with.
Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: For the questioner's benefit, you might want to mention the name of this algorithm. It's [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), and it was invented some time before 300 BC. Euclid was probably not its inventor, but was the first to document it (in a work that has survived at least).